# In Backbone, can't get object's id or cid after using "create" function to add it to Parse

Tags: parsing, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone and Parse to build a survey website. I imitated the Todo list example to add a question to the page. As in the todo list example, I have "createOnEnter" and "addOne". Getting the id is important to me because I need to set the id of the question the same as its id in Parse.

```
    addOne: function(question) {
    alert(question.get("content"));
    alert(question.id);
    var view = new QuestionView({model: question});
    this.$("#questions").append(view.render().el);
},

    createOnEnter: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode != 13) {
        return;
    }

    this.survey.create({
        content: $("#new-question").val(),
        type: $("#choose-type").val(),
        order: this.survey.nextOrder(),
        user: Parse.User.current(),
        ACL: new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current())
    }, {wait: true});
        $("#new-question").val('');
    }
```

So alert(question.get("content")) will indeed gave me the expected content but alert(question.id) shows undefined. However I believe each entry saved to Parse will get a unique id so I couldn't understand why question.id is undefined. Even worse, alert(question.get("cid")) is also undefined.....This is really confusing to me.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ids` are given by the server (when you `fetch` and the server return an `id` fields). It could also get added if when you create your model you manually add an `id` field - but the point is that this isn't done automatically. `id` is the unique identifier of a resource **on the server**.

As you're creating question on the frontend, you'll need to use the unique id Backbone create who's called `cid` . http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that if I do alert(question.get("cid")) it also return "undefined": <

Comment: Yeah, you need to do `alert(question.cid)`. As `cid` isn't synced with the server, it's not considered to be an `attributes` (and in theory, it's not considered to be changeable - and it shouldn't).

Comment: And if you want to retrieve it inside a `Collection`, you'll need to use `getByCid` method instead of `get`: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-getByCid

Comment: Been a pleasure. If it answer your question, you can mark the answer as accepted by pressing the big check top-left near the vote counter. Good luck for your project